# design and analysis data with SQL or Python

Tags: database

After learning the basic concepts of SQL server I wonder what is the difference between (SQL server) and (libraries like Pandas, Numpy, Matplotlib, and seaborn in python) for analyzing data?
also could someone help me, what learning path should be taken first for becoming a big data architecture? (by considering the fact that my degree is not computer science)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python Libraries are used for analysis of data using a python program. It is used for the analysis of data using python which is generally in the form of .CSV file.

Whereas SQL is used for database.

Inshort: when working on a database, we will use SQL. When working on a dataset which would generally in the format of .CSV file, we will use python Libraries.

You can start with a small project such as house price prediction in order to learn these concepts.